# Download and run a WGET file

Tags: python, wget

I would like to download a model from the site. These are WGED files, which I first download and then open in VSCode! However, I cannot get the file to run! What do I have to do?

Source: https://esgf-node.llnl.gov/search/cmip6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> These are WGED files

No, they are `.sh` files, which are text files, if you open one in text editor you will see that first line

```
#!/bin/bash
```

meaning that said file is supposed to be used with [`bash`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)), moreover following comment might be found

```
# first be sure it's bash... anything out of bash or sh will break
```

thus implying you need functional `bash` in order to make any use of said file.

Comment: Thx! I failed to use it cause I don´t have any permission! But thanks :-)